# how to merge large set of images to one image

Tags: image, merge, photoshop

I have let say 128 images . Now I want to merge it as one like 16*8 grid as one image. any software can handle this much image? I used picture merge genius but it can handle 64 images in my m/c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, ImageMagick is free and installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows.

Let's say your images are named `frame000.png` to `frame254.png`, and they get successively lighter in colour as their frame number increases. You can use the `montage` command in ImageMagick like this:

```
montage -tile 16x -geometry +0+0 frame*png montage.png
```

[image]

The `16x` means that it will be montaged in rows of 16 images. If you want it 16 rows tall, you can use `x16` instead of `16x` - i.e. the number before the `x` is the width and the number after `x` is the height.

The `-geometry +0+0` means to place the images abutting each other without gaps, if you want the images 5 pixels apart horizontally and 10 pixels apart vertically, use this:

```
montage -tile 16x -geometry +5+10 frame*png montage.png
```

[image]

If you want the images on a red background, use this:

```
montage -background red -tile 16x -geometry +5+10 frame*png montage.png
```

[image]

Comment: little late from my side! simply superb...explained nicely. thanks a lot!   I have one more Question to you is that when i merge say 5x5 of 1.5mb(1400x700 px) each so total 25x1.5 mb would be the final image size. but its less than that why?

Comment: I guess it is a result of the compression algorithm having an easier time of it with the bigger image and it can just get set up once for the whole image and get on with it more efficiently.

Comment: 1 problem i'm facing. image is not merged accordingly. suppose I have image0-image10 ,it should merge 0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10. but it is jumbled can you please inform me?

Comment: Your filenames are not naturally sorted from the computer's point of view - i.e. for your computer `image10` comes before `image2` because the `1` is before `2` in its ordering sequence. You either need to name your files with leading zeroes, i.e. `image00`, `image01`, `image02`, or specify the images in the order your want into the `montage` command with `montage -tile ... image{0..10} ...`

Comment: thanks for the help! same thing i tried in picture merge genius there it works(but has some limitation unlike IM).